# How to implement a stack with push and pop in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, stack, queue

I'd like to implement a stack data structure (not to be confused with the Flutter Stack widget) in Dart so that I can handle a stack of custom TextStyles for Flutter text rendering.

I know with stack you can push and pop values. This sounds similar to Queue, but I'm not sure of the difference.

This doesn't work:

```
final myStack = Queue<int>();
myStack.push(1);
final top = myStack.pop();
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A stack is a first-in-last-out (FILO) data structure. If you make a stack of books, the first book you put down will be covered by any other books that you stack on top of it. And you can't get that book back until you remove all of the other books on top of it.

[image]

#### Implementation

You can implement a stack a number of different ways. The original version of this answer (see [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64060945/revisions)) used a `Queue` as the underlying data structure. However, the [default Dart Queue itself uses a list](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/sdk/lib/collection/queue.dart), so it seems like a `List` is the more straightforward approach. Here is how I would implement a stack now:

```dart
class Stack<E> {
  final _list = <E>[];

  void push(E value) => _list.add(value);

  E pop() => _list.removeLast();

  E get peek => _list.last;

  bool get isEmpty => _list.isEmpty;
  bool get isNotEmpty => _list.isNotEmpty;

  @override
  String toString() => _list.toString();
}
```

**Notes**:

- To **push** means to add a value to the top of the stack. This is implemented here with `_list.add`, which is a fast O(1) operation.
- To **pop** means to remove a value from the top of the stack. This is implemented here with `_list.removeLast`, which is a fast O(1) operation.
- To **peek** means to get the value of the top element in the stack without actually removing it. This is implemented here with `_list.last`, which is a fast O(1) operation.

#### Nullable implementation

When using the above implementation of stack, you would normally check `isNotEmpty` before trying to `pop` or `peek` because doing so on an empty stack would cause the underlying `List` to throw an error. However, if you prefer to check for `null` instead, you can make `pop` and `peek` nullable:

```dart
E? pop() => (isEmpty) ? null : _list.removeLast();

E? get peek => (isEmpty) ? null : _list.last;
```

#### Usage

You can use your `Stack` like so:

```dart
void main() {
  final myStack = Stack<String>();

  myStack.push('Green Eggs and Ham');
  myStack.push('War and Peace');
  myStack.push('Moby Dick');

  while (myStack.isNotEmpty) {
    print(myStack.pop());
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Moby Dick
War and Peace
Green Eggs and Ham
```

Comment: In the pop, you can simplify the pop by assigning the return of `_stack.removeLast()` to  `lastElement` (and maybe just returning that, without the variable)

Comment: @L3n, yes, you're right. There are a number of other changes that do now when making a stack, so I rewrote the entire answer. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the default Queue implementation uses a list but not a List. It uses ListQueue actually.

Comment: @lig, If you check out the implementation of `ListQueue`, it uses a `List`.

Comment: @Suragch I see it, right. However, there are some growth optimizations. The underlying list won't grow often and elements are being moved around a lot.
So, it looks like there is no benefit in using Queue a Stack. The List could be even faster as there is less logic involved.

Answer (score 7):

here is the class I use

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class Stack<T> {
  final _stack = Queue<T>();

  int get length => _stack.length;

  bool canPop() => _stack.isNotEmpty;
  
  void clearStack(){
    while(_stack.isNotEmpty){
      _stack.removeLast();
    }
  }

  void push(T element) {
    _stack.addLast(element);
  }

  T pop() {
    T lastElement = _stack.last;
    _stack.removeLast();
    return lastElement;
  }

  T peak() => _stack.last;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

My version of a Queue wrapper:

```
import "dart:collection" show Queue;

class Stack<T> {
  final Queue<T> _underlyingQueue;

  Stack() : this._underlyingQueue = Queue<T>();

  int get length => this._underlyingQueue.length;
  bool get isEmpty => this._underlyingQueue.isEmpty;
  bool get isNotEmpty => this._underlyingQueue.isNotEmpty;

  void clear() => this._underlyingQueue.clear();

  T peek() {
    if (this.isEmpty) {
      throw StateError("Cannot peek() on empty stack.");
    }
    return this._underlyingQueue.last;
  }

  T pop() {
    if (this.isEmpty) {
      throw StateError("Cannot pop() on empty stack.");
    }
    return this._underlyingQueue.removeLast();
  }

  void push(final T element) => this._underlyingQueue.addLast(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified the other answers' versions, to make use of nullable.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class StackCollection<T> {
  final _queue = Queue<T>();

  void push(T element) {
    _queue.addLast(element);
  }

  T? pop() {
    return this.isEmpty ? null : _queue.removeLast();
  }

  void clear() {
    _queue.clear();
  }

  bool get isEmpty => _queue.isEmpty;
  bool get isNotEmpty => _queue.isNotEmpty;
  int get length => this._queue.length;
}
```

Also renamed to `StackCollection`, to avoid interference from the [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map`.

Notice that `peek` and `peekN` methods have O(1) complexity (expected).

```
class Stack<E> {
    final LinkedHashMap<int, E> _map = LinkedHashMap <int, E> ();

    void push(E value) => _map[_map.length + 1] = value;

   E? pop() {
     E? value = _map[_map.length];
     _map.remove(_map.length);
     return value;
   }

   E?  peek () => _map[_map.length];

   E?  peekN (int n) => _map[_map.length - n];
 }
```